# Remove display pid in bash when runing background

Tags: bash, background-process

If we run process in background we see process pid and output:

```
# echo cho &
cho
19078
```

Is it possible to make:

```
# echo cho &
cho
```

---

**Why I need this?**

I want to write simple inline LAN-scanner with only pings for some PC which have no utilities like `nmap` or `arp-scan`.

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{1..254}; do (ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo ">>> ${ip} is up"; ) & done
```

It works but PIDs spoil output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(echo cho &)
```

In loop:

```
for ip in 192.168.23.{1..254}; do (ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo ">>> ${ip} is up"  &) done
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d just run the `for` loop itself as a single job in the background. There’s also no need to use parentheses to run any commands in a subshell (with Bash, using the `&` control operator automatically creates a subshell to run the commands). The less processes that are forked within the loop, the quicker it will run.

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{1..254}; do ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null &&
    echo ">>> ${ip} is up"; done &
```

If you don’t want *any* job control feedback to be printed to screen, you can enclose the backgrounded loop in parentheses so that it runs within in another subshell level:

```
( for ip in 192.168.1.{1..254}; do ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null &&
    echo ">>> ${ip} is up"; done & )
```

---

A **better solution** would be to redirect the output of the `echo` statements to a file and keep the job control output so that the shell can notify you when the loop has finished. You can keep using your shell and avoid having the terminal getting cluttered with output printed by the loop running in the background.

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{1..254}; do ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null
    && echo ">>> ${ip} is up"; done > hosts_up &
```

---

*Note:* The above commands can be run as one-liners but I use two lines here to avoid horizontal scrolling (`&&` at the end of a line means the rest of the command continues on the following line).

Comment: You run all job in bg, so it will take 1 sec * 254, and it still writes one pid